# Is it possible to make a graphical snap for Ubuntu Snappy on the RPi?

Tags: gui, snap, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I would like to know how to make a snap with a GUI for the raspberry pi running Ubuntu Snappy Core. I have unfortunately not been able to find any good resources on this, if anyone knows any, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A better resource for snap development and packaging is http://snapcraft.io

Comment: @user535733 yes, I know this, what I meant was there are not many resources on how to do this, and I was wondering if anyone could recommend some please.